# WiFi not working on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. my laptop is hp15bs576tx.  It was recently bought from Amazon. it's i5 7 gen with 8gb ram. It was bought for 45000. Despite of being such a modern laptops it doesn't support WiFi. There is no way I can switch on WiFi. There is a icon that has WiFi symbol but there is nothing inside. If it is a driver problem then I can't understand that what is the use of having such an expensive laptop. Also the sound is very low. Pls help me how can I get WiFi working on my device

Here is the output

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel modules: wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I tried the steps but in vain